# Creating a GUI with executable button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I am using Python27 on Window7 OS, i am trying to create a Tk GUI with button, when the button is press a file directory will appear. But the following code won't do anything. Did i miss out something?

```
import webbrowser
import Tkinter as Tk

def action(self):
    webbrowser.open ('C:\AgmPlots')

win = Tk.Toplevel()
frame = Tk.Frame(master=win).grid(row=1, column=1)
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command= lambda: action())
```

Comment: A couple of side notes: `lambda: action()` does exactly the same thing as just passing `action`, except that it's more complicated, less readable, and slower. And you don't normally want to add a `self` parameter on a function; that's for _methods_ in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got three big problems.

First, you never start the GUI. You need something like `win.mainloop()` at the end to actually do anything.

Second, your button isn't actually laid out within the frame, so you won't see it. You need something like `button.pack()`.

Finally, your `command` is a function that calls `action()`, with no arguments. But you've defined it to require a parameter. So, all that will happen when you click it is that Tk will log a traceback that looks like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "tkt.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command= lambda: action())
TypeError: action() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

To fix that, either don't add the unnecessary `self` parameter to `action` (this is a function, not a method), or explicitly pass some dummy to match it in your `lambda`.

While we're at it, `lambda: action()` does exactly the same thing as `action` itself, except more verbose, harder to read, and slower. You should never use unescaped backslashes in non-raw string literals. And we might as well remove the stray spaces and PEP8-ify everything to make it consistent.

So, putting it all together:

```
import webbrowser
import Tkinter as Tk

def action():
    webbrowser.open(r'C:\AgmPlots')

win = Tk.Toplevel()
frame = Tk.Frame(master=win).grid(row=1, column=1)
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='press', command=action)
button.pack()

win.mainloop()
```